# How to initiate the parameters in accLoacation() method of Iaccessible interface?

Tags: c++, com

I try to retrieve the screen location of a element with accLocation() method of Iaccessible interface, but have trouble to initiate the parameters of the method

```
IAccessible *plocation;
long *x;
long *y;
long *width;
long *height;

VARIANT varChild;
varChild.vt = VT_I4;
varChild.iVal = CHILDID_SELF;

hr = pIaccessible->GetIAccessible(&plocation);
hr = plocation->accLocation(x, y, width, height, varChild);
```

But when I run it, the error messages come like:

```
    uninitialized local variable 'x'used,
    uninitialized local variable 'y'used,
    uninitialized local variable 'width'used,
    uninitialized local variable 'height'used
```

Comment: you are giving as argument to `plocation->accLocation()` uninitialized pointers. If they are output arguments they should be previously allocated either on heap or on stack.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling, you need to use:

```
long x;
long y;
long width;
long height;

...

// Pass the addresses of objects where the values can be stored.
hr = plocation->accLocation(&x, &y, &width, &height, varChild);
```